# how to use an array to replace parts of a string

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I have an array of values `['123', '456', '789']` what approach can I use to iterate over this array and replace, in matching sequence, parts of a string that have the value `:id` (for example `users/:id/games/:id/server/:id`)?

At the moment, I've been toying around with a `.forEach()`, but the initial value isn't getting updated per iteration. Curious how the following example could be altered in a way that would allow me to pass in an updated version of the string with one less `:id` on it.

#### goal:

input: `{ target: 'users/:id/games/:id/server/:id', ids: ['123', '456', '789']   }`

output: `'users/123/games/456/server/789'`

```js
const injectPathVariables = (
  target: string,
  ids: string[]
): string => {
  let newStr: string | undefined;
  ids.forEach(id => {
    if (newStr === undefined) {
      newStr = target.replace(':id', id);
      return;
    }
    newStr.replace(':id', id);
  });
  return newStr;
};
```

Comment: What's your input, and expected output? You should add those to your question and try to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let string = "users/:id/games/:id/server/:id";
const arr = ["123", "456", "789"];
arr.forEach((i) => {
  string = string.replace(":id", i);
});

console.log(string);
```

Here it is in [action](https://codepen.io/riza-khan/pen/VwWKOrx?editors=0012).

Answer (score 0):

Array.[forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) irritates the array.

Array.[map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) irritates the array and **returns** a new array.

```js
const injectPathVariables = (
  target: string,
  ids: string[]
): string => {
  let newStr: string | undefined;
  ids.map(id => {
    if (newStr === undefined) {
      newStr = target.replace(':id', id);
      return; // this will result in replacing id with Undefined 
    }
    newStr.replace(':id', id);
  });
  return newStr;
};
```